# Can't install mercurial package with pip under python-3.2

Tags: python-3.x, mercurial, pip

I try to install mercurial with pip package manager with command:

```
pip.exe install mercurial -I --install-option="--c2to3"
```

and get such error:

```
Downloading/unpacking mercurial
  Running setup.py egg_info for package mercurial
    setup.py with python3 needs --c2to3 (experimental)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    setup.py with python3 needs --c2to3 (experimental)

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
```

**How to pass "--c2to3" option to setup.py correctly via pip options?**

System: Server2008R2 SP1, python-3.2.3(AMD64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercurial [isn't supported on Python 3.x](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/SupportedPythonVersions). Install it under Python 2.7 (unless you want to help port it)

Comment: This seems rather lame.

Comment: The link (http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/SupportedPythonVersions) is broken. The mercurial wiki has moved to https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/SupportedPythonVersions